# IE9 not rendering [display: table] CSS correctly?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I have an MVC 4 application that is using Bootstrap. Part of the Header on the application is your typical *Username* and *Password* fields with a *Login* button and *Remember Me* Selection.

In Chrome everything renders correctly:

[image: LoginRenderIssue-Chrome]

But in IE9 I see this:

[image: LoginRenderIssue-IE9]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-6 box">
        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <div class="profileLinks">                    
                <a href="@organizationUrl">My Organizational Profile</a>
                |
                <a href="@userProfileUrl">My Profile</a>
            </div>
            <div class="content logout">                
                <div class="row">
                    <div>
                        Hi, @User.Identity.Name
                        @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account", new {},new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" })
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="E-mail" required tabindex="1"/>
                        <a href="#" ><h6>Forgot your username?</h6></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required tabindex="2" onkeyup="EnterKeyPressed()"/>
                        <a href="#" ><h6>Forgot your password?</h6></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="button" id="loginButton" value="Login" onclick="login()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" tabindex="3" onkeyup="EnterKeyPressed()"/>
                        <br />
                        <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe">Remember Me
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

As best I can tell, IE9 seems to be having some sort of issue with the `.row` class from `bootstrap.css`. Does anyone have some ideas for how I might fix the rendering in IE9 to match that of Chrome, with the *Username*, *Password*, and *Login Button* fields all on the same respective "`row`"?

Comment: You may need to use an actual table for your code to work on all browsers. :(

Comment: Yes. Or at least have a DOM tree that can be changed into table elements (`table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`). What do you hope to accomplish by creating tables with nothing in them except a single space?

Comment: Chrome might display this in a way that pleases you, while IE doesn't, but that doesn't count as "rendering correctly". What you have there are not correct tables, and there is no correct way to render incorrect things.

Comment: @MrLister, You make a good point in the above. I found the solution, posting shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by adding the following, everything was rendering as I desired in IE, as well as Chrome and Firefox:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

`IE=edge` runs the page in the most up to date version of IE available.